# How to use bmpdata.draw(component); on Flex 4 SPARK components?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, draw, flex-spark, bitmapdata

So I try to say `bmpdata.draw(backgroundRect);`  to dray on my Bitmap my component but Flash Builder gives me this and I do not know what to do...

*1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type spark.primitives:Rect to an unrelated type flash.display:IBitmapDrawable.   Flex Problem*

Please help

Comment: Can you share more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use backgroundRect.displayObject. You might wanna set

```
backgroundRect.displayObjectSharingMode = DisplayObjectSharingMode.OWNS_UNSHARED_OBJECT
```